# object oriented javascript - inheritance implementation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two module with very similar methods (it is a part of an adapter pattern that implements the same methods/interface). The differences are in two lines of code:

```
function MyModuleA{

}

ModuleA.prototype.myMethod = function{
           --LineA--
           --LineB--
           --LineC--
           --LineD--
}

function MyModuleB{

}

ModuleB.prototype.myMethod = function{
           --LineA--
           **--LineE--**     //different line
           --LineB--
           --LineC--
           **--LineF--**     //different line
           --LineD--
}
```

Can I use javascript inheritance to implement the similar lines only once?

Thanks!!

Comment: It might depend on what the lines of code are, but generally yes. WHy don't you try it?

Comment: I have a problem because the similar and different lines are mixed... Hoe can I call a base class in this case?

Comment: Put the consecutive lines of shared code into different functions. Then call the functions you need in the base classes. You may not want to do this because grouping the code based on this minute similarity might not be worth it, but that's not what you were asking.

Comment: Indeed, I was looking for a better solution, if exists...

Comment: Anything i can think of that would do this with inheritance would be pretty clunky. Either split the code into functions as mentioned above, or use `if` statements around the dissimilar code to only run it under the ModuleB.